# JQuery Hide on page load with 'starts with', can't unhide later

Tags: jquery

I want to hide a div when I load the page. Its a dynamic div though that gets assigned a class name, and then a number is added based on other criteria.

So I have this.

```
$(function() {
  $("[class^='myClass']").hide();
});
```

Problem is, later, when I try to show the div, I only want to show one of them. So I try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[class^='showDiv']").click(function() {
    // I use the showDiv value (array index) to get the specific
    //  class I need to now show

    $(".myClass2").show();

  });
});
```

Problem is, it doesn't show my class.  I think its because the 'hide' function is hiding everything starting with 'myClass'.  And it kind of overrides when I try to show the specific '.myClass2' since it is being hidden by the earlier hide.

I can't unset the hide though. otherwise all of the elements show up.

I'm lost what to do here.

Thanks.

EDIT

I tried this, and it works.

instead of the just hiding at the beginning, I do this.

```
$(function() {
      $("[class^='myClass']").each(function( index ) {
          $(".myClass" + index).hide();
      });

    });
```

And that works fine. So I'm pretty sure the hiding a class from the begining with a 'wild card' is what my problem is..

Is there a better solution than this?

Comment: I think [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) will be better

Comment: We need to see the associated html. If you have any of these classes nested will be a problem since you can't show a descendent of a hidden element

Comment: Check the actual CSS that gets applied to your dive using the browser debugger. Also is the class you are trying to show dynamically determined, it looks like it is from your example.

Comment: I updated my question, I will try to put together a Jsfiddle if possilbe to show more of the problem. I've never made one before though.

Comment: @NickBailey Yeah, the class is also dynamically determined

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
one-to-one relation sample

[jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/xww0vtee/1/)

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('.myClass').hide();

    $('.showDiv').click(function() {
        var index = $('.showDiv').index(this);

        $('.myClass:eq(' + index + ')').toggle();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="showDiv">showDiv</div>
    <div class="showDiv">showDiv</div>
    <div class="showDiv">showDiv</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="myClass">myClass 1</div>
    <div class="myClass">myClass 2</div>
    <div class="myClass">myClass 3</div>
</div>
```